# Can not startBeforeActivity at an activity defined in a subprocess

Tags: camunda

I have a parent process where a subprocess is started with "callActivity". The subprocess contains two tasks, task1 and task2. When I try to start the parentProcess at "task1" or "task2", I get a NotValidException:

```
org.camunda.bpm.engine.exception.NotValidException: Element 'task2' does not exist in process parentProcess:1:324: targetElement is null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.EnsureUtil.generateException(EnsureUtil.java:380)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.util.EnsureUtil.ensureNotNull(EnsureUtil.java:54)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.StartProcessInstanceAtActivitiesCmd.determineFirstActivity(StartProcessInstanceAtActivitiesCmd.java:123)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.StartProcessInstanceAtActivitiesCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceAtActivitiesCmd.java:69)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cmd.StartProcessInstanceAtActivitiesCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceAtActivitiesCmd.java:46)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:27)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.execute(ProcessApplicationContextInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.executeWithVariablesInReturn(ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.java:165)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.execute(ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.java:131)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.execute(ProcessInstantiationBuilderImpl.java:127)
```

Here is how I try to start the process at "task2".

```
runtimeService.createProcessInstanceByKey("parentProcess")
    .startBeforeActivity("task2")
    .execute()
```

To contextualize a little: we need to migrate old process instances into new definition, so we need to be able to start at any user task in the process.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, it would appear that you're attempting to start an instance of the parent process definition at a step that's only valid in the (child) subprocess definition. Is that correct?

If so, then the behavior you're seeing is the intended behavior, and you would need to specify an activity in the parent process definition.

There are options that you could leverage to start the subprocess instance at a specific step once that subprocess invocation is encountered in the parent instance, but that isn't supported by the Call Activity and would need to occur via a Java API call, which could be done in either a Service Task or a Script Task.